# Excel VBA comparing longer strings with inconsistency

Tags: vba, excel

I have have three excel columns: "description" and "usage" is in sheet 1, "descr and usage" in sheet 2.

Description and usage is combined to one sheet and it is seperated with either a title ("Description:" and "Usage") or with a Entertab.

Description always starts with a small letter (Excel when starting with a name) and description always starts with a capital letter.

Sometimes the description ends with a period and sometimes not.

[image: Example of how the columns looks like are shown here]

These columns are part of a very big and old file. Some of the data has been manually inserted when the IT-system was first implemented, this is why there is so many inconsistensy.

Now I want to make an automatically comparison, but I dont know how to handle all the inconsistency, how do I do?

Comment: Clean up the database with search and replace? :-)

Comment: I don't have access to the database T_T I Think it is not possible too since the database is handled by other people...

Answer (score 0):

partial code:

```
s$= cells.value
while right(s,1)=" "
s=left(s,len(s)-1)
wend
s = ucase(    left(s,1) ) & right(s,len(s)-1)
cells.value = s
```